# How to check the closure in a subset of $S_4$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $H = \{ \sigma \in S_4| \sigma(4) = 3 \lor \sigma(4) = 4 \}.$ I need to check if this is a subgroup of $S_4.$ I can show that the neutral element and an inverse of all elements of $H$ is in $H$ but I have a problem in showing the closure of the product inside $H.$ I tried to represent the elements of $H$ in cyclic form so as to easier prove if the condition $\sigma(4) = 3 \lor \sigma(4) = 4$ will still hold in the product. I need to distinguish between many cases. In some of them I can find the product is closed but not in all of them. Maybe I am doing some mistakes. I am wondering if there is a more straightforward way to check the closure of the product. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you sure about the inverse?

Comment: What about the cycle $(2\ 4\ 3)$?

Comment: Thanks. The inverse is $(3 4 2)$ and thus $\sigma^{-1}(4) = 2 \neq 3 \lor 4. $